# JorgChart not loading properly in chrome but working fine in IE10

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, jquery-ui, internet-explorer

I am working on a organization Chart which was created using jQuery 1.7 and JorgChart plug in.
When I am trying to load the orgChart using IE,it is loaded as expected.
But when I am trying to load the chart using Chrome it is not rendering the chart axis properly although node are loaded as expected....

Comment: please provide relevant code and output and what is to be expected

Comment: var $linesRow = $("<tr/>");
                $childNodes.each(function() {
                    var $left = $("<td>&nbsp;</td>").addClass("line left top");
                    var $right = $("<td>&nbsp;</td>").addClass("line right top");
                    $linesRow.append($left).append($right);
                });

Comment: .jOrgChart .line {
  height                : 20px;
  width                 : 4px;
}

.jOrgChart .down {
  background-color   : black; 
  margin     : 0px auto;
}

.jOrgChart .top {
  border-top          : 3px solid black;
}

.jOrgChart .left {
  border-right          : 2px solid black;
}

.jOrgChart .right {
  border-left           : 2px solid black;
}